# How to convert array to the result of `dd($variable)` (laravel)?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5.3

My array is like this :

```
$data = array(
            'number'            => '395364128', 
            'user'              => 'becks',
            'store'             => 'becks store', 
            'total_amount'      => 11000000, 
            'total_product'     => 2,
            'status'            => '92000000', 
            'delivery_address'  => 'spain',
            'email'             => 'becks@gmail.com'
        );
```

I want to convert the array to the result of `dd($variable)` on the laravel like this :

[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: I didn't fully understand the question. You want to convert the array to a string returned by dd funciton? then use ```dd($data)```.

Comment: @aceraven777, I want when run : `dd($data)`, the result like image above

Comment: Then use ```dd($data)```. The output will be the same as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
$user = new User();
$user->fill($data);
dd($user);
```

[Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_fill](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_fill)